# Celery tasks not returning results from redis

Tags: flask, redis, celery

How can I get the results of a task from redis? I want the query results that the task returned and not the status of the tasks.

Log files verify that the task returns the results. According to [these docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#results) `get()` can be used to return the task results and according to [these docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#tips-and-best-practices) it should work. Something tells me I am not actually saving the results to the redis backend.

Expected Behavior:
Run the task every 24 hours and store the db query results in redis. Use the redis cache to get those results on application calls.

Here is my task function.

```
@shared_task(name='get_top_ten_gainers', ignore_result=False)
def get_top_ten_gainers():
    from collections import namedtuple
    query = (
        db_session.execute(
            """WITH p AS (
            SELECT CompanyId,
            100 * (MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CloseAdjusted END) / MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CloseAdjusted END) - 1) DayGain
            FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
            FROM DimCompanyPrice
            )
            WHERE rn <= 2
            GROUP BY CompanyId
            ORDER BY DayGain DESC
            LIMIT 10
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM p
            JOIN Company ON p.CompanyID = Company.ID"""
        )    
    )
    logger.info(query)
    
    Gain = namedtuple('Gain', query.keys())
    gains = [Gain(*q) for q in query.fetchall()]
    payload = [[g.Symbol, g.Security, g.DayGain] for g in gains]
    logger.info("`payload` of type {}: {}".format(type(payload),payload))

    return payload
```

Here is my flask view helper function:

```
def _top_ten_gainers():
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    
    from project.tasks import get_top_ten_gainers
    
    result = get_top_ten_gainers.apply_async()
    logger.info("`result` of type {}: {}".format(type(result),result))
    logger.info("`result.get()` of type {}: {}".format(type(result.get()),result.get()))       
    
    total_payload['gainers'] = result.get()
    logger.info('task finished in {}'.format(time.perf_counter() - t0))
```

Here is the celery ouput:

```
 -------------- celery@desktop v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.11.0-41-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 2021-12-02 18:07:16
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x7fb6f8bb5b80 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
[2021-12-02 18:07:17,276: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
[2021-12-02 18:07:17,287: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-12-02 18:07:18,305: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2021-12-02 18:07:18,320: INFO/MainProcess] celery@desktop ready.
[2021-12-09 15:08:01,235: INFO/MainProcess] Task get_top_ten_gainers[26ce0da8-662c-4690-b95e-9d1e42e79e34] received
[2021-12-09 15:08:05,068: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] <sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x7f40c876e970>
[2021-12-09 15:08:05,087: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] `payload` of type <class 'list'>: [['MA', 'Mastercard', 3.856085884230387], ['GM', 'General Motors', 3.194377894904976], ['LH', 'LabCorp', 2.6360513469535274], ['CCI', 'Crown Castle', 2.491537650518838], ['DHI', 'D. R. Horton', 2.451821208757954], ['PEAK', 'Healthpeak Properties', 2.3698069046225845], ['BDX', 'Becton Dickinson', 2.355495473352187], ['DD', 'DuPont', 2.19100399536023], ['HLT', 'Hilton Worldwide', 1.9683928319458088], ['JKHY', 'Jack Henry & Associates', 1.7102615694164935]]
[2021-12-09 15:08:05,090: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Task get_top_ten_gainers[26ce0da8-662c-4690-b95e-9d1e42e79e34] succeeded in 3.8531467270004214s: None
```

Here is my log file output:

```
[2021-12-09 15:08:01,216][index       ][INFO    ] `result` of type <class 'celery.result.AsyncResult'>: 26ce0da8-662c-4690-b95e-9d1e42e79e34
[2021-12-09 15:08:05,068][tasks       ][INFO    ] <sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x7f40c876e970>
[2021-12-09 15:08:05,087][tasks       ][INFO    ] `payload` of type <class 'list'>: [['MA', 'Mastercard', 3.856085884230387], ['GM', 'General Motors', 3.194377894904976], ['LH', 'LabCorp', 2.6360513469535274], ['CCI', 'Crown Castle', 2.491537650518838], ['DHI', 'D. R. Horton', 2.451821208757954], ['PEAK', 'Healthpeak Properties', 2.3698069046225845], ['BDX', 'Becton Dickinson', 2.355495473352187], ['DD', 'DuPont', 2.19100399536023], ['HLT', 'Hilton Worldwide', 1.9683928319458088], ['JKHY', 'Jack Henry & Associates', 1.7102615694164935]]
[2021-12-09 15:08:05,090][index       ][INFO    ] `result.get()` of type <class 'NoneType'>: None
```

Comment: How did you verify that what the function returns is actually wrong? Did you try to run the function outside Celery excution environment and verify that it does not return None?

Comment: @DejanLekic I've updated my question with more logs. The query results are logged to the application log file and they are also logged to the celery logs. I believe a task returns None when it is successful which makes sense in this situation but then the question becomes, how do I get the query results that the task supposedly stored in redis

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your task is taking ~4 seconds and you're not waiting for it to finish.
You can wait for it like that:

```
def _top_ten_gainers():
    from project.tasks import get_top_ten_gainers
    result = get_top_ten_gainers.delay()
    while not result.ready():
        sleep(1)
    gains = result.get()
    logger.info("Task results: {}".format(gains))
```

Comment: Per the docs ‘get’ waits until the task is ready, and returns the result so shouldn’t I not have to manually check until there’s a result?

Comment: Interesting, did you try to add logs between the lines to see if it actually waits? do you know what's the default `timeout`?

Comment: @sat1017 did you give it a chance?

Comment: Does not solve the problem. I have a hunch that the query results are not being stored in redis or that I am not properly getting them.